# Robospice - In what order should we use execute(), addListenerIfPending(), getFromCache()

Tags: android, caching, listener, robospice

There are three possible states of request when we enter an activity.

1. Not yet started
2. In process, listener is detached
3. Request complete

From the documentation, I understand if we use execute() in onStart(), it takes care of cases 1,3 but not case 2(when request is in process). We need to use addListenerIfpending() for that

Workaround I used is use addListenerIfPending() in onStart(), and use execute in onRequestNotFound()

```
protected  void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    getSpiceManager().addListenerIfPending(my.class,"mykey",new myRequestListener());
}


    public final class myRequestListener implements PendingRequestListener<result> {

    @Override
    public void onRequestFailure(SpiceException spiceException){

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestSuccess(final RoundInfo roundInfo) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestNotFound(){

        getSpiceManager().execute(request,"mykey", DurationInMillis.ONE_DAY,new myRequestListener());
    }
}
```

I want to know if this is the correct way, the way it's meant to be done.

Also, please comment if there will be any performance issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your first statement is wrong.

`execute()` will take in charge all 3 cases.

`addListenerIfPending` will not trigger any request by itself, it only allows to plug a listener to an already pending request if such a request exists. So case 2.

Comment: so just simply use execute() in onStart() ?